# Cloud Functions - Android application crashe when getHttpsCallable() call

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, android-virtual-device

I try to call functions in **firebase emulator** from my android project.

I follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#java_2 , but when i call getHttpsCallable, my AVD stop and I don't see any error in logcat or event log.

Here is a shorter code than in the course which don't work too.

In android Studio: (java)

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String TAG = "DebugTest";

    private DatabaseReference mRef ;
    private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button clickBtn = findViewById(R.id.clickBtn);

        // WARNING: firebase emulators
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance("http://10.0.2.2:9000?ns=nameOfMyApplication-xxxxx")
                .getReference();



        //crashe when I click on the button
        clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("hello").call();
                        
                    }
        });
    }
}
```

In index.js

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.hello = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return `Hello world!`
})
```

the function is not call in log of firebase emulator suite .

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the `mFunctions` variable, you just declared it. Try adding the  code below next to the initialization of the firestore that you are already doing and it should work:

```
mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
```

---

EDIT:

To log the return of the function you will have to change your `onClick` function to the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println(mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("hello").call().getValue());                      
}
```

Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: thank you very much! my app don't crash. However i don't see any log in my emulator. is this normal??

Comment: Well, given the code that you have, yes, since you are not logging the return of your Cloud Function, you are simply calling the function and not doing anything with it's return in your android code. I will edit the answer to add this, please remember to accept and upvote it if it solved the issue :)

Comment: the output of the function is a Task. And i have the code error INTERNAL

Comment: You are correct, I just fixed the code, should work now.

Comment: I can't use getValue. In addition when i use console.log in my index.js the log is not visible so i think this is an other error. I will create an other post cause the original instance probleme is solve.

Comment: I think i forgot to use firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5000')  in index.js but i don't find the module which gives firebase

Comment: so, you want to log from the cloud function and not from the android one?

Comment: I want to use my localhost to run cloud function

Comment: Have you follow [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)?